# Jquery AutoComplete with ASP validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am new to webforms and i ran into problem i have two different text box one used jQuery auto complete and other has asp:validation . so when i add asp:validation to TextBoxProjectName my jquery autocomplete for SearchTxt fails and if i remove my validation from TextBoxProjectName the jquery fires perfectly for SearchTxt

```
        <asp:Label ID="searchlabel" Text="Search " runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTxt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control txtSearchProgram" Width="90%" AutoPostBack="true" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 w-100 mt-3" style="display: inline-block">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ShowAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-main " OnClientClick=" return BtnSend_Click()" align="center"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row  m-4 " id="ShowOnClick" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-4 w-100">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelProjectName" Text="Add Project Name " runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxProjectName" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control " Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
       <%-- <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TextBoxProjectNameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxProjectName" CssClass="invalid-feedback elementToValidate"
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="txt">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 w-100">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelProjectLink" Text="Add Project Link Use Format  <span style='color:red'>*</span>(https://google.com)<span style='color:red'>*</span>" runat="server" Style="display: block"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxProjectLink" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="false" Width="90%" ></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
     <div class="col-4 w-100">
       <asp:Label ID="LabelGroupName" Text="Add Group Name " runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxGroupName" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control " Width="79%" Style="display: inline-block"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" ValidationGroup="txt" CausesValidation="true" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-main" OnClick="Add_NewProject" align="center"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    runat="server" 
    Display="Dynamic"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?"
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxProjectLink"
    ErrorMessage="Input valid Internet URL!"
    ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
```

Comment: It might help to add `ValidationGroup` to the validator to separate which controls are affected.

Comment: it was because jquery was loading twice got it fixed .In master page Jquery was used twice jquery.min and jquery-3.3.1 was included as well took one off and it worked